# Is it possible to have KDE 5.6 and Unity 8 side by side?

Tags: unity, kde, desktop-environments

I'm yet new to Ubuntu, so this might be a quite silly question. The point is, there are many desktop environments out there, each of them with its advantages and disadvantages.

My question is: if I just got a new installation of Ubuntu, it comes with Unity 7. Is it possible to install both Unity 8 and KDE 5.6 and keep them side by side  without compatibility issues?

What I mean by "side by side" is having the two installed and being able to choose on login which one of them I'll use.

I've seem already on the internet some examples where people install a different desktop environment, and on the login screen there appears the options.

The only thing I'm concerned about is compatibility. I'm worried that one might break the other.

So is it possible? And if it is, what is the correct way to have both installed side by side without breaking each other?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can install them side-by-side. There will be an option to select a desktop at login. However, Ubuntu 16.04 only provides Plasma 5.5, not 5.6, so you would need to enable the [Kubuntu Backports](https://launchpad.net/~kubuntu-ppa/+archive/ubuntu/backports) PPA.

If you only want the desktop, and not any of the applications, the kubuntu-desktop package will install everything you need. If you want essentially a Kubuntu system, install kubuntu-full.

Comment: Please upvote or accept this answer as correct if it's helpful.